# ROS Debug Clion - Controller

Tags: ros, controller-manager, clion

I have following problem. I am using clion and ROS (1). I use franka_ros to develop a controller.

Hear I want to mention, that I followed all the steps provided by clion - documentation website, to set up ROS in clion. Everything works fine. I can debug simple executables. I could also attach to a simple running executable node.

Now, I want to debug my written controller, based on franka_ros. I use a launch file and the "controller_manager"-package to launch the complete world. Everything works fine.

But my problem is, that I cannot attach to the process and debug the controller. First thing I notice, that the executable of the controller spawner process is "python3" and available debuggers are "Python/Native". When I attach to the process with the debuggers I cannot stop at breakpoints or get any information of my controller at all. I think it might be a problem of having the "controller_manager"-package in between.

Does anybody has some ideas or experiences with that ? Any hint or recommendation would be nice!

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific reason you are using CLion and don't want to move away from it? Ros has several tools for working on the command line that you are missing out on. Also, based on what you are trying to do, you may use `pdb` and use the `set_trace()` method for debugging on cli

Comment: @AkhilKurup Thanks for your recommendations.

Most of that is personal preference. I am flexible of doing another approach, but I would like to use an IDE if i can. 

Isn't pdb only for python ? I found there exists gdb for c++, but it seems it can also pe problematic for .so files and if it is launched by an ros-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general resource you'll likely want to look at the documentation for IDE integration on the ROS wiki at: https://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#CLion

What I think that you're running into however is that controllers are often run as injected components in a separate main loop and are loaded and unloaded dynamically. This means that if you want to debug them at runtime you need to attach your debugger to the main that the controller is going to run inside, and not the small launcher script which I speculate is what you're seeing as a python script, that's only sending a request to the controller manager.

Without more details in the question I think that's about as complete an answer as can be provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I helped me to solve my problem. In my case (using gazebo & ros) I needed to attach to the running "gzserver" process.

Comment: @klanky Please use the check mark to accept either mine or Martin's answer so that others know your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Attach during runtime to the controller manager process, not to the spawner.

Also figure out which .so file is loaded - whether it's the one from your workspace, or the one from clion's own build folder. For debugging, you'll want the latter (cmake-build-debug). This can be found when you attach to the controller manager, press pause button in clion, switch to the gdb panel and type `info sharedlibraries`. It will list all loaded .so files. To force loading clion's .so file, you can put the absolute path of the .so in environment variable LD_PRELOAD (e.g in the launch file using `<env>` tag).